# is it possible to use the existing drivers for the hls lfcd lds to communicate with an arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to bypass all of the turtlebots other components and just use its lidar module to talk with an arduino, I have taken a look on the support page and investigated the drivers, however im unsure as to what items would need to be used to make a usable arduino library for it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287558/is-it-possible-to-use-the-existing-drivers-for-the-hls-lfcd-lds-to-communicate-with-an-arduino/) by [sneakycoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/34009/sneakycoder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenCR (support Arduino) has example for hls-lfcd-lds

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/tree/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/OpenCR/examples/10.%20Etc/LDS/drawLDS

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-05**:
@Darby Lim instead of posting a link, can you please put a self-contained example? That will make this answer self-contained and won't force people to go to another site, look at three different files, and read almost 500 lines of code.